# Creating a constrained 3D Random Walk [Python]

Tags: python, math, statistics, random-walk

I have an implementation of a random walk in 3D that can move in 6 directions at random to create random looking 3D points. Currently this approach creates purely random surface plots. I am trying to add the following constraints to the random walk 1) Make it symmetrical 2) make it closed. Is it possible to add the following constraints to the random walk process so that the random walk will create symmetrical and closed point clouds.

My current implementation to create 3D random walk is below

```
N = 100 # choose number of steps, granularity
R = (np.random.rand(N) * 6).astype("int") # randomly intialize 1 array with 6 moves: 0,1,2,3,4,5 and 100 steps, combinations
x = np.zeros(N) # 100 x steps
y = np.zeros(N) # 100 y steps
z = np.zeros(N) # 100 z steps

# define the random moves
x[ R==0 ] = -1 # left
x[ R==1 ] = 1 # right
y[ R==2 ] = -1 # down
y[ R==3 ] = 1 # up
z[ R==4 ] = -1 # back
z[ R==5 ] = 1 # front
x = np.cumsum(x) # cumulative sums the steps across for each axis of the plane
y = np.cumsum(y)
z = np.cumsum(z)
```

Comment: "Symmetrical" is essentially the antithesis of "random".  Are thinking you'll generate the walk in one quadrant, then reflect it in the other 7?  (I guess with 8 things, they aren't really "quadrants".)

Comment: @TimRoberts - I agree, symmetrical is essentially defeating the whole random process here. I am really not sure as to how I could achieve symmetry. 1. One way I was thinking was to generate it in one quadrant and then repeat it in 8 and find the largest continuous structure(blob) 2. Generate the random 3d walk and then graph cluster to get the largest symmetrical shape.

Comment: Karthik, sounds like an interesting problem, but it's not clear what you mean by symmetry. What kind of symmetry do you want to impose? Can you point to some diagrams or images which illustrate the kind of symmetrical path you want? About generating a closed path, one idea is to generate a set of guide points at random, and then generate a path from one point to the next. One way to generate the point to point path is to pick a point at random, and then move it. You can repeat that process -- pick a point on each new subinterval and move it. This is a method for generating fractal shapes btw.

Comment: @RobertDodier - By Symmetry, I want a configuration of points or a shape that will look the same on both halves when cut in the middle  Regarding your fractal idea, I did some research on that. Are you suggesting I do something like a snowfllake fractal to create infinitely closed surfaces? At the end of the day my requirement is to create a random cluster of points that are symmetrical and closed

Comment: Okay, given that you want a symmetric, closed path. You mentioned you're working in three dimensions. One way to get a symmetric closed path is to start from a given point on the X axis, and then wander until you reach the YZ plane (i.e, until X = 0). Keep that trajectory. Now start again from the same point, and again wander until you reach the YZ plane. Now append the two trajectories, and reflect every point across the YZ plane. Presto! You have a closed, symmetric random path in three dimensions.

Comment: A difficulty with that approach is that it may take many steps before you reach the YZ plane, if the initial point is far from the YZ plane. At least one way to reduce the number of steps is to pick a point on the YZ plane at random, and construct the line segment from the initial point to the new point. Now choose a random point on that segment, and add a random displacement. For each of the two resulting segments, repeat the process -- choose a point at random on the segment, and displace it. The path becomes more and more fractal-like as the segments are repeatedly broken and displaced.

Comment: @RobertDodier, Upon thinking about it, I think I just need it to be symmetrical in the x-y direction and doesn't need to be in the z direction. So I was thinking if the symmetry can be achieved by repeating the image in all the remaining hree quandrants and that will help in symmetry and I will just need to worry about the closed path